# when i click 1 time unity is registering 2 clicks instead of 1;

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a gun script, whenever i click, my ammo needs to decrease by 1, but sometimes i click once and unity is decreasing by 2, i firstly tried  `ammo--;` then i tried `ammo -= 1` but its the same:

this is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Gun : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Gun Raycast Things")]
    [SerializeField] private Transform raycastPos;
    [SerializeField] private float gunRange = 50f;

    [Header("Particles")]
    [SerializeField] private ParticleSystem particleSystem;

    [Header("Ammo")]
    [SerializeField] private float ammo = 30f;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject reloadAnim;

    public float gunDamage = 20f;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R) && ammo != 30)
        {
            reload();
        }
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }

    private void Shoot()
    {
        if (ammo <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        ammo -= 1;

        RaycastHit hit;

        if(Physics.Raycast(raycastPos.transform.position, raycastPos.transform.forward, out hit, gunRange))
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.collider.tag);
            Debug.DrawLine(raycastPos.transform.position, hit.point);

            Target target = hit.transform.GetComponent<Target>();
            if(target != null)
            {
                target.OnHit(gunDamage);
            }

        }

        particleSystem.Play();
        Debug.Log(ammo);
    }

    private void reload()
    {
        reloadAnim.GetComponent<Animator>().Play("GunReloadAnimation");
        ammo = 30f;
    }
}
```

Comment: `firstly tried ammo--; then i tried ammo -= 1 but its the same` .. it is indeed exactly the same ^^

Comment: add a bool flag to prevent duplicate entries when procesing your shoot. I.e.:  private void Shoot()
    { working = true) 
and on call: 
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
if (!working){
            Shoot();
}
        }

Comment: @joreldraw how would that prevent the whole thing being executed twice? ;) If you anyway reset the flag inside the method itself then right the next time it can be called again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general rather get user Input in `Update` not in `FixedUpdate`!

You might miss input or if you have a lower frame-rate `FixedUpdate` might get called twice in a frame.

See [`FixedUpdate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)

> The FixedUpdate frequency is more or less than Update. **If the application runs at 25 frames per second (fps), Unity calls it approximately twice per frame**, Alternatively, 100 fps causes approximately two rendering frames with one FixedUpdate.

So it totally depends on your frame-rate and physics settings.

As said in general you should rather get single event user Input frame wise:

```
void Update()
{
    // you might want to consider to also here use GetKeyDown depending on your desired gameplay
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R) && ammo != 30)
    {
        reload();
    }

    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {
        Shoot();
    }
}
```

Comment: i will try, i think that this is the problem since have a lower spec pc but i will see, thanks.